# JPA, Mysql Blob returns data too long

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, blob

I've got some `byte[]` fields in my entities, e.g.:

```
@Entity
public class ServicePicture implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2877629751219730559L;
    // seam-gen attributes (you should probably edit these)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String description;

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private byte[] picture;
```

On my database schema the field is set to `BLOB` so this should be fine. Anyway: Everytime when I try to insert a picture or pdf - nothing bigger than `1mb`, I only recieve this

```
16:52:27,327 WARN  [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22001
16:52:27,327 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Data truncation: Data too long for column 'picture' at row 1
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [de.ac.dmg.productfinder.entity.ServicePicture]
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:629)
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:218)
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(EntityManagerInvocationHandler.java:46)
16:52:27,328 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy142.persist(Unknown Source)
```

I've checked my MySQL cnf and the `max_allowed`param is set to `16M` - am I missing something?

Comment: Solved it by this link http://enricogi.blogspot.com/2008/12/blob-type-in-mysql.html - in short - MySQL Blob has max size of 64k

Answer (score 137, accepted):

It all depends on the column type used for the `picture` column. Depending on your needs, use a:

- `TINYBLOB`: maximum length of 255 bytes
- `BLOB`: maximum length of 65,535 bytes
- `MEDIUMBLOB`: maximum length of 16,777,215 bytes
- `LONGBLOB`: maximum length of 4,294,967,295 bytes

Note that if you generate your table from the JPA annotations, you can "control" the type MySQL will use by specifying the `length` attribute of the `Column`, for example:

```
@Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(length=100000)
private byte[] picture;
```

Depending on the `length`, you'll get:

```
       0 < length <=      255  -->  `TINYBLOB`
     255 < length <=    65535  -->  `BLOB`
   65535 < length <= 16777215  -->  `MEDIUMBLOB`
16777215 < length <=    2³¹-1  -->  `LONGBLOB`
```

Comment: The upper bound of `LONGBLOB` should be `2^32 - 1` instead of `2^31 - 1`.

Answer (score 3):

I use below and it works for images

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "file", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
private byte[] file;
```

Answer (score 2):

In our case we had to use the following syntax:

```
public class CcpArchive
{
    ...
    private byte[] ccpImage;
    ...
    @Lob
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "CCP_IMAGE", columnDefinition="BINARY(500000)")
    public byte[] getCcpImage()
    {
        return ccpImage;
    }
    ...
}
```