# How to insert an Image URL for Images stored in Postgres into a Spring Boot Model

Tags: arrays, spring, postgresql, kotlin

I have built an app with a Spring Boot Gradle Kotlin Backend, that can store and upload Multipart files to a Postgres database. The data is stored in a ByteArray. So far everything is working fine.

Now I want to add an Image URL to make it available in my JSON Object to later grab it and display it on my client side like the ones on Unsplash.

**imageURL**

```
"imageURL": "https://xyz.jpg"
```

**File model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
data class File(
    @Id
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    val createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    var updatedAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    var likes: Int = 0,
    var likedByUser: Boolean = false,
    var description: String = "",
    val downloadLink: URI = URI("https://unsplasy-backend.herokuapp.com/files/download/$id"),
    var name: String = "",
    var type: String = "",

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private val data: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(),

    val imageURL: TODO = "TODO"
)
```

**Store**

```
    fun store(file: MultipartFile): File {
        val fileName = file.originalFilename.toString()
        val fileToSave = File(
            name = fileName,
            type = file.contentType.toString(),
            data = file.bytes
        )

        return fileRepository.save(fileToSave)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve image from blob via Hibernate (not JDBC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049488/retrieve-image-from-blob-via-hibernate-not-jdbc)

Comment: Yes, thank you I figured it out. I am not sure if this is the best way but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the suggestion above I came up with this and it works.
**Controller Update**

```
@GetMapping("/files/image/{id}")
    fun displayImage(@PathVariable id: UUID, response: HttpServletResponse) {
        val file = fileService.getFile(id)
        val data = fileService.getData(file)
        response.contentType = file.type
        response.outputStream.write(data)
        response.outputStream.close()
    }
```

**File Model update**

```
val imageURL: URL = URL("https://unsplasy-backend.herokuapp.com/files/image/$id"),
```