# how can we store image in database (mysql with php)

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I store and retrieve images from a MySQL database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php)

i want store and fetch image from mysql database. is anybody i have knowledge about this.

Thanks in advance.
Ravi Sharma

Comment: A Google search with that string produces any number of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the image contents (use `file_get_contents` function) into field of type BLOB. Another solution to decode binary data with function `base64_encode` and store in simple TEXT type field.

Answer (score 0):

You can store images in a Blob-type column.

Check out the comprehensive tutorial [here](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/storing-images-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to store images in your database. You want to use the filesystem and only store image meta data in the database, like the filesystem path.