# file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path

Tags: image, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, file-get-contents

My image is uploading to images/news successfully. I want to now save that image in the database. but it keeps giving me the above error. My model query is correct because i use it to insert other data and it works.

How can i save the image into the database once the user clicks submit?

My controller:

```
 function news()
{

 $config = array(
'upload_path' => "./images/news",
'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|JPG",
'overwrite' =>False,
'max_size' => "2048000", 
'max_height' => "768",
'max_width' => "1024"
);
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    if($this->upload->do_upload())
{
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
 $this->load->view('manage_news',$data);
}
else
 {
 $message2 = "Please choose another file type. gif,jpg,png,jpeg,pdf ";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message2');   </script>";                 
          redirect('resetPasswordController/add_news', 'refresh');
       }

        $this->db->trans_start();

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $data = array(          
            'image' => file_get_contents( $data )
            );

         $this->load->model('users_model'); 
        $this->users_model->insert($data);    

        $this->db->trans_complete();
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        redirect('resetPasswordController/manage_news', 'refresh');
  }
```

my view:

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('resetPasswordController/news');?>
 <label>Image</label>
<input name = "userfile" type="file" />
```

my model:

```
 function insert($data){
        $this->db->insert('news',$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: Just for Your information: You must not save files to database, that'll make Your life difficult later. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723707/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-database-using-php-script/8723739#8723739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$data contain array values, you have to use upload_data

for ex :

$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

```
$data = array(          
    'image' => file_get_contents( $data )
    );
```

change this to

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $data = array(          
            'image' => file_get_contents( $data['upload_data'] )
            );
```

or

you can directly use upload data function

```
            $data = array(          
                'image' => file_get_contents(  $this->upload->data())
                );
```

Comment: try direct file path file_get_contents(  /* upload file paht */ );

Comment: this is what i did:    $data = array('image' => file_get_contents( "./images/news" )  );

Comment: where is your file name put your full file path

Comment: this worked -> $imagename = $this->upload->data(); $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());