# Saving pChart image to mysql

Tags: mysql, png, pchart

I need to save the png that pchart creates to my mysql database.

Is there a function that will retrieve the binary data of the png the is created?

This is what i tried to add to the pChart library but it just returns one.

```
 function getPicture()
{
    return $this->Picture;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very difficult, this is has been asked and answered on stack overflow:

[How can I store and retrieve images from a MySQL database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the pChart library will be linked to a database in order to retrieve dynamic data.please take a look to this [tutorial](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=faq.mysql)

Comment: Hello I am not sure how this applies to what I am trying to do. pChart renders a png to file using the Render() function all i want to do is grab that data that gets rendered to file and put it into the db