# Broken image icon displays while trying to display a BLOB

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob

Okay, so my end goal is to display an image (or multiple in a blog type style) that is stored in a database(*MySQL*) as a *blob*. Right now it display a broken image icon ([image]). This is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('HOST','USER','PASS!') or die("Could not connect to database");
    $dbsel= mysql_select_db('DATABASE', $link) or die("Couldn't select database.");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bmblog");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

        echo "<img src='php/imgView.php?imgId=".$row['media']."' />";

        echo "<center>" . "<font color='white'>" . "<FONT FACE='timesnewromans'>" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['msg']));

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    };

?>
```

Also

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($row['media']) . '" />';

echo "<center>" . "<font color='white'>" . "<FONT FACE='timesnewromans'>" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['msg']));
```

Both display the same broken image icon. I did notice however without trying to echo the second line (of *text*) I did get a full boarder around the broken image icon that would have been about the size of the image. This is not the same for the first method though.
I've been searching for a few hours now and have found tons of post about this, but none that seemed to work for me or make sense, I am fairly new to PHP so this may be something simple I am missing; Either way thank you in advance for any help it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer to test this perhaps?

Comment: what code is in imgView.php?

Comment: I have tried: Opra, Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Firefox; same issue with them all :/

Comment: None, it does not exist. I'm guessing this is my problem (I took that code from another answer that was not explained at all, just the code)?

Comment: look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: After trying that it still doesn't work (now it displays nothing at all) and gives this message: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\THEWEBSITE.com\webroot\index.php:202) in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\THEWEBSITE.com\webroot\index.php on line 209 Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\THEWEBSITE.com\webroot\index.php on line 210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might solve the problem is the to add [`header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) just before you `print/echo` the image.

Also it is strange that `base64` example you included would not have worked. When I looked at the example provided, the first line of the `Also` section the `echo` opens with double quote(") and end with single quote('). This might cause exception and why you couldn't test base64 properly.

It must be:

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($row['media']) . '" />";
```

You can also add a charset: `data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,`

Lastly, I would suggest looking at the following example that might help

[How to Base64 encode your images](http://lucdebrouwer.nl/how-to-base64-encode-your-images/)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, it returned with this error message headers already sent by (index.php)

Comment: I tried your: echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($row['media']) . '" />"; 

And it tells me there is a single quote left open but honestly I can't find where.