# How can I retrieve all the stored images from sqlite in mainActivty?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to insert the image, delete the images and retrieving all the images from SQLite database. I am creating the database with code shown below.

But how can I call these methods in `MainActivity`?

```
public class Imagehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {     
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="abhi.db";
        private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1; 

        public Imagehelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
            }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Image(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,imageblob BLOB);");
            }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }       
        public Cursor getAll() {                
            return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT imageblob FROM Image",null));
        }   
        public void insert(byte[] bytes)
        {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

            cv.put("imageblob",bytes);
            Log.e("inserted", "inserted");
            getWritableDatabase().insert("Image","imageblob",cv);
            System.out.println(":vlfkv: " +cv.size());
        }
        public byte[] getImage(Cursor c)
          {
              return(c.getBlob(1));
          }

        public void deletePhoto(String id) {

            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();    
            String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM  Image where _id='"+ id +"'";
            Log.d("query",deleteQuery);     
            database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php link

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Please go for this tutorial, it will help you alot in the long run: http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html

Comment: Make **Imagehelper** object and initialize it and access your method which you want in your Activity..

Comment: You should storage image path and use anywhere. [Check one simple Local database example here](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/sqlite-database-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an instance of your `Imagehelper` in your Activity :

```
Imagehelper mImageHelper = new Imagehelper();

// and then you can access your methods ...
mImageHelper.insert(yourValue);
mImageHelper.get(yourValue);
mImageHelper.deletePhoto(yourValue);
```

I suggest you follow some dabatase tutorials for Android :

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: how i can i am using getAll method in my main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

use this code. where image is byte array. Getting all images as `byte[]` code u  have already written

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not call select query in **getImage** method. so see below function.

```
public byte[] getImage(
{
   Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT imageblob FROM Image",null);               
   return(c.getBlob(1));
}
```