# store image in sql and retrive it in php

Tags: php, mysql

I've create a table where I've saved images through "LongBLOB". I need to show those images.
i can save images in my sql but when i want to read and display them i have a problem,
"can not be displayed because it contains errores"

im usi8ng this code to save the image to my sql table

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "imgtest";
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database);
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {
    $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);
$namee = $_FILES['image']['name'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO image(cap,image) VALUES ('$namee','$data')");
}
    ?>
```

and im using this code to read and display the image from my sql table

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imgtest");
$wich=$_POST['wich'];
$resoult=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM image WHERE id LIKE '$wich'");
$imgd = $_GET['img'];
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resoult);
$image = $row['image'];
header("content-type:image/jpeg");
echo $image;

?>
```

anyone can help me with this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I store and retrieve images from a MySQL database using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: This is a mix of old code, using a deprecated API, and the modern method. Strange. Also, change your password)

Comment: $pstenstrm i used that code but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly advised to store images within your file structure (a directory on your server, cloud server, or other accessible location) and only keep a reference such as a url,  file name or path path in the database in order to recreate a link or path to the actual image. It is a bad practice to keep images in a database.

Comment: thank you for ur answer Silvertiger i know its a bad idea. but i need it!can u help me ?

Comment: Why is it bad practice to store images in a database

Comment: it makes ur data base so much larger!

Comment: Any queries you run have to scan through the entire image data to iterate (i.e. searches, matches, filters, joins, etc.) making your queries run slower and slower the larger your database grows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you using `mysql_` library - it is deprecated.
2. You need to store binary data. Use prepared statements. In that way you get back binary data.
3. From 2 you can dump `addslashes`. That is the root of the problem

Comment: i just changed the data to binary but nothing changed!and in code 1 when i remove addslashes i cant save the file in my sql anymore! and i dont get any error!

Comment: @user3719210 - Are you using mysqli library and prepared statements

Comment: yes i did.can anyone make simple example and post it here so i can use the code?