# Which is heavier, base 64 string or hexadecimal or binary

Tags: php, binary, hex, size, base64

I have this app which stores images in base 64 string in database. Storing in disk is no option here. However,

1. I would want to choose the lightest between base 64, hex and binary. Can anyone help, please.
2. I also appreciate conversion from base 64 to either of the other two.

I am using PHP

Comment: Use the hard drive with a pointer to it.

Comment: If by "binary" you mean dual/bitwise representation, the expansion ratio would be 1:8. (And hex is 1:2, for base64 it's 1:1.3̅)

Comment: Thanks @php_purest, but I have said using disk is no option.

Comment: What DB are you using?  Possible dup:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: @wrschneider99 MySQL. I'll check the post. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use: file_put_contents  Is it disabled on the server?

Comment: @php_purest, no it is not disabled. The app dictates that I use DB to store images.

Comment: @wrschneider99, the question you pointed to is not exactly the same. I am not asking HOW to store image in DB. I have already done that. And, it is working. I only need to consider a LIGHTER option.

Comment: back ends are back ends, you can always write a tiny image storage unit on the back end.

Comment: I know that. In fact, I did that successfully many times. But THIS TIME, I just need to use DB.

Answer (score 0):

Binary would hold the data in the smallest size, then base64 then hex.

Base64 to binary

```
$binarydata = base64_decode($bas64data);
```

binary to hex

```
$hexdata = bin2hex($binarydata);
```

Note with binary storage you can't just echo out the image data in an `<img>` tag, you have to set up some kind of viewing page or just re-encode it in base64.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this straightforward answer. I'll try the solution and then comeback to upvote if works.