# Getting broken image retrieving BLOB with PHP

Tags: php, html, image, blob, store

Just for the record, this is being done with Wordpress (I Didn't choose it nor to store the images in a DB either).

Basically I'm trying to store and image in a Database using php and showing it later, but i am getting a broken image icon. (trust me i've been researching this and I can't find what's wrong).

This is how i store the image:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="img" id="media">
```

PHP:

```
$item['media'] = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']));
$result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);
```

And this is how im trying to retrieve it:

HTML:

```
<img src="Image_View.php?image_id=<?php echo $item["item_id"]; ?>"/>
```

Image_View.PHP:

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  $result =  $wpdb->get_row("SELECT media FROM $wpdb->item WHERE item_id = 3", ARRAY_A);
  header("content-type: image/png");
  echo $result["media"];
?>
```

BTW! this is my first question in Stackoverflow! so HI EVERYONE!

---

**Edit 1:**

As hanshenrik mentioned, $wpdb->insert is escaping the input, so i uploaded and image then wrote it to disk, set the proper exntension and BOOM there you go, now i know im actually uploading the image the proper way, but it looks like im still having troubles trying to show it, when using chrome's developer tool im getting this:

GET http://127.0.0.1/pymes/wp-admin/Image_View.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

So, is something wrong with the Image_View.php ? the query is actually good and is retrieving the data since i copied and pasted that code in another place and it echoed the whole lote of characters inside of the bin file.

---

**Edit 2:**

Again! sorry for being late on this, i've been working

So, the solution for my problem while uploading the image has been explained in Edit 1 (thanks to hanshenrik for suggesting that wpdb insert was escaping the input).

Regarding showing the image, i was having troubles with Headers being sent before it could make it to:

```
header("content-type: image/png");
```

so i was struggling at this and I decided to try using URI for the image, which solved my problem. For me this is more a workaround rather than an actual fix, but it floated my boat. the way i implemented the URI is as follows:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result =  $wpdb->get_row("SELECT media FROM $wpdb->item WHERE item_id = $_GET[id]", ARRAY_A);

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($result['media']).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
?>
```

By doing this I don't longer need the Image_View.php file.

Really appreciate the help provided here, TY guys!

Comment: Hi back! I think the most likely thing is that the image has been corrupted by the `addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']));` when you stored it

Comment: I think I might have converted the image to `base64` and then stored that if I had to store an image on a MYSQL database. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding)

Comment: Simple test, read the blob from the database, write it to disk with the correct extn. If you cannot open it with a image viewer, then it got naffed by the store proceedure.

Comment: you are right!, i already tried changing the extension and i couldn't open it.

Sorry for being late, i didnt thought someone was going to answer me as i saw the question going down and down hhaha

Comment: So, what could i do, it would be great if u know of any guide that i could follow, im kinda new to this and in most of the examples that i found they used the addslashes funtion @RiggsFolly

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: ok, i took a look at the link in your first comment, let me see if i got this right, i should use something like this: $base64 = base64_encode($imagedata); instead of the addslashes and store its result ?

Comment: Or this tutorial http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html which does nothing with the image before storing it.

Comment: Cannot be any more help, I have never been in the situation of having to do this. I woudl always store images on disk with just a reference to them in the database

Comment: Ok, i'll try those and report, TY very much bro! @RiggsFolly

Comment: Yea I would love to know what actually was wrong and even more what actually works

Comment: i don't know if i should be doing this but @RiggsFolly question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution for my problem while uploading the image has been explained in Edit 1 (thanks to hanshenrik for suggesting that wpdb insert was escaping the input).

Regarding showing the image, i was having troubles with Headers being sent before it could make it to:

header("content-type: image/png");
so i was struggling at this and I decided to try using URI for the image, which solved my problem. For me this is more a workaround rather than an actual fix, but it floated my boat. the way i implemented the URI is as follows:

get_row("SELECT media FROM $wpdb->item WHERE item_id = $_GET[id]", ARRAY_A);

echo '';
?>
By doing this I don't longer need the Image_View.php file.

Really appreciate the help provided here, TY guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
$item['media'] = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']));
$result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);
```

addslashes? are you crazy? use a proper SQL escape function, if $wpdb->insert does not escape for you.

anyway, with your current code, this might work..

```
 echo stripslashes($result["media"]);
```

or perhaps

```
echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($result["media"]));
```

Comment: WOW! looks like you nailed it! apparently $wpdb->insert does escape de data! maybe that was the trouble =#  ill try this!

Comment: data:

(array) Data to insert (in column => value pairs). Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped). From wp codex

Comment: ok! so far so good, i skipped the addslashes and now when i write to the disk the image and set the proper extension i can actually see it (something i couldn't do before!)

Comment: i don't know if i should be doing this but @hanshenrik question updated.

Comment: ..now i want to see the exact html generated by your script :p

Comment: sorry for being late i managed to solve this, ill update the question explaining how i did it asap.  @hanshenrik