# How to convert blob data in MS-SQL and MySQL to it's original form using java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, oracle

In our product,when we run a project (Say 'ABC') that inserts blob data into the database(can be MySQL/Oracle/MS-SQL) , but when we execute a select query and retrieve a blob data from database to convert it to original form using java (Here we are writing this output to a file) then the following block of code fails for MySQL but works perfectly fine for MS-SQL.Can we build a code snippet in generic way ?

```
int length = blobData.length();  
    byte[] data = new byte[length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < length ; i += 2)
data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(blobData.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(blobData.charAt(i + 1), 16));//Note : blobData is of String type
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php This may help you :)

Comment: @Shivam It is good but we can not use it in that way.

Comment: I do not think you can have generic solution. For example BLOB in Oracle is BinaryStream (or CharStream for CLOB). LOBs can be HUGE and converting them into arrays in not safe.

Comment: @ibre5041 What do you suggest instead of arrays ?

Comment: Get the BLOB through [`ResultSet.getBlob()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBlob%28int%29). Then, convert it to a `String` with `String blobAsString = new String(blob.getBytes(0, blob.length()), Charset.forName("ENCODING_OF_DATA"))`, where `ENCODING_OF_DATA` is the charset encoding used for the character data.

Comment: @SudeepMasare use `ResultSet.getBlob().getBinaryStream()`. And then read BLOB data piece by piece. For String data use CLOBs instead of BLOBs. The max size of BLOB is 176TB, you probably do not have so much RAM for your JVM heap.