# Storing image file name in db and actual file in server vs Storing image data in database and loading the image with script.

Tags: php, mysql, database, image-processing, blob

I am working on a small social media project and one of the things I want todo is allow users to upload an image. I originally was thinking about uploading the actual file to a image directory and saving the files name in the database to call it later.

However there is a limit to how many files I can have in a directory, and file size can be an issue.

So instead of going this route I looked into simply saving the image data using php's `file_get_contents()` function to the database as a BLOB datatype and then writing another script that renders an image from the image data.

This kinda seems like a no-brainer and a better route since image data would be relatively small in size.

I am worried though because it seems like its too convenient. Is there a reason why I shouldn't do this? I mean a real viable reason? Is something gonna bite me in the ass later because I am going this route?

I hope this was the right place to post this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If one or more answers are correct you should accept (and upvote if appropriate) one so other users of this site know which one is best and correctly answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that serving images from a database is usually much, much much slower than serving them from disk. It'll start a PHP process, create the database connection, query the database, transfer it and then pushing out via PHP which would be non-cacheable.

There are some complexities to storing images in a database but it does allow for easier sorting and deleting, and you can perform additional checks if security is of concern, and logging if that is of interest.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1638348/5509627 for implementation.

If disk space is only concern you may consider storing the images in AWS S3 or similar.