# upload multiple images and inserted into separate field in table using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, image-upload, multifile-uploader

I am not very well in PHP. I want to upload two images separately and stored those in two different field in table. My HTML code is as below :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="News Slider">
                <input name="img" type="file" required id="sortpicture"/>
                <input name="img2" type="file" required id="sortpicture"/>

                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Save and Submit" class="btn btn-app">Save and Submit</button>
              <button type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset the Form" class="btn btn-app">Reset the Form</button>

              </form>
```

My table structure is like ImageId | image_name | image_thumbnail

I wrote code as below, but it stores only img2 (second selected image) image in image_name and image_thumbnail field. But img (first selected image) is not storing any where.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
     {

        if($_FILES['img']['name']!='')
    {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
        $namefile = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
        $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
        $image_name=time().".".$ext;

        $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"uploadnewsslider/".$image_name);


    }



    if($_FILES['img2']['name']!='')
    {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["img2"]["tmp_name"];
        $namefile2 = $_FILES["img2"]["name"];
        $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile2));
        $image_thumbnail=time().".".$ext;

        $fileUpload2 = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img2']['tmp_name'],"uploadnewsslider/".$image_thumbnail);
    }


         $sql="insert INTO newsslider(image, thumbnail) VALUES ('$image_name', '$image_thumbnail')";
         mysql_query($sql,$connection);
         }
```

In detail, I want to upload two images from two separate browse button from my form and then store those into two separate fields (i.e. image_name and image_thumbnail) in table.

Here you can see that I have two input file type (img and img2) and I want to store those in two different fields (image_name and image_thumbnail) in a table.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I store and retrieve images from a MySQL database using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: Dear, I dont want to store and retrieve solution of an single image. But I want to upload multiple image and store them in separate field in a table.

Comment: What's the problem about copying the answer *twice* so you get two images instead of one? If you're not capable to do this, you should learn basics of PHP first.

Comment: I did this, copying answer twice and renamed variables like : `if($_FILES['img2']['name']!='')
        {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["img2"]["tmp_name"];
            $namefile2 = $_FILES["img2"]["name"];
   $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile2));
   $image_thumbnail=time().".".$ext;

            $fileUpload2 = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img2']['tmp_name'],"uploadnewsslider/".$image_thumbnail);
        }
   
    
    $sql="insert INTO newsslider(image, thumbnail) VALUES ('$image_name', '$image_thumbnail')";
    mysql_query($sql,$connection);
    }`

But it stores same images twice. Pls help

Comment: Please update your question with the properly formatted code you're having problems with. Look at [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have edited my question and tried to explain my problem in details. Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [Using another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375013/multiple-upload-images-into-mysql-database/47366585#47366585) multiple image

Answer (score 1):

You uploaded first file:

```
$fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"uploadnewsslider/".$image_name);
```

But you *didn't insert* it to the database.

So if you want to store two images in separate fields you need to:

1. Modify your table schema so it can store two images instead of one(i.e. `id | image1 | image1_thumb | image2 | image2_thumb`)
2. Give different names to the variables that hold the images (i.e. $image1_name, $image2_name etc)
3. Insert **both** images in one query.

I hope it was clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I wrote query like `$sql="insert INTO newsslider(image, thumbnail) VALUES ('$image_name', '$image_thumbnail')";
         mysql_query($sql,$connection);`

I have also mentioned two different variables (img and img2) and table schema like `ImageID | image_name | image_thumbnail`

Please clarify where I did wrong.