# How to store more then 50000 images into godaddy hosting without increasing the INODE number?

Tags: html, xml, image, jpeg, inode

I'm building a big database wich I show detail and images for every mountain huts and peaks.

The trouble is that there are 24000 mountains and 5000 huts into my db and for every record I've 4 jpg.

My hosting plan unlimited (godaddy) provide me unlimited disk space (the image size is not a problem) but there is a INODE Limit (max number of file on the server) fixed to 250000.
I may stay into this limit but I want to know if in some method I can store image into one file like XML and binary images)
In any case the image should be readable by individual link like this:
website.it/images/waypoints/"name of the mysql field"/"name of the mysql field"-number.jpg

Can someone help me?

thank you :)

Comment: You can try to save the image as a binary blob type in the database - not the actual file - then convert it from blob to image on the fly. Refer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: Besides database, you can also store the blob data in xml or JSON if you wanted file format (and can combine the 4 images for each into one file). Depending on what technology you are using, you can do this with JavaScript, .NET, PHP...

Comment: Ok, thanks I use PHP for my serverside so I get a look to my godaddy hosting plan and I've notated that my MySQL DB can't be higher than 1GB and so I prefer to store Image as large blob into XML file, Is it possible?