# MySQL BLOB image too big on website

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store images as BLOBs in my database. I know this isn't the optimal solution but it'll have to do for now as it is a small database. When I upload the photo it takes up way too much space as shown and is cut in half. Is there a way to resize it into a thumbnail. I don't have access to any html pages and only limited access to php files. I can only manipulate the database. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: Image is too wide and cut in half]

Comment: Show us the code or it didn't happen

Comment: Might be useful to add some code to this question

Comment: What kind of code would like to see? As I said I have very little access to code in this situation. I have to use a PHP generator which generates all the code for me and generates html too. I can only view html code by viewing the source of the page.

Comment: *"it takes up way too much space as shown and is cut in half"* - That's because BLOB is too small. You need to either use MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB. And yes, there is a way to resize them before uploading. You can easily find that in a search.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using a LONGBLOB

Answer (score 0):

Yu can have look at [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php)

But it is rather good to save Image in Folder And Creating link for it and insert it is database...

e.g.

```
$fileName = $_FILES["image"]["name"]; 
$fileNameNew = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $fileName);
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
// Path and file name
$pathAndName = "My-Image-Folder/".$fileNameNew;
// Run the move_uploaded_file() function here
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
// Evaluate the value returned from the function if needed
```

And Then Add `$pathAndName` in database...