# I am trying to display an image in php

Tags: php

can somebody help me with this little problem here. I am a newbie and I am trying to display an image with a blob data type from my post database table. I do not know where am i going wrong but here is my code.

```
$res = $conn->query("SELECT post.postid, post.message,post.photo, post.posted_on, users.username FROM 
                          post INNER JOIN users ON post.userid = users.userid ORDER BY
                          post.posted_on DESC LIMIT 10");
   $result = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            20204040
            $image = $row['photo'];

            $result.= '<hr/><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div  class="w3-light-grey w3-padding w3-round-xlarge w3-margin-60">'.
            '<strong> @'.$row['username'].'</strong>'.
            '</span>'.'<br/> '.
            '<span class ="ka">'.$row['message'].'</span>'.

            '<img src="image/$image"/>'.

            '<br/>'.
            '<span class="fa fa-comment w3-text-indigo"></span>'.
            '<a href="#" id="'.$row['postid'].'" class="w3-text-indigo w3-small w3-border-0 w3-light-grey"'.
            ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#replyModal">'."Reply".'</a>'.
            '<span class ="w3-tiny">'.$row['posted_on'].'</div></form>';


    }
```

Comment: instead of `'<img src="image/$image"/>'.` use `"<img src='image/'".$image."'/>".`  . Also try once to give full path instead of `image/`

Comment: You know that if you want to include HTML in with PHP content, instead of trying to jam all the HTML code into a single PHP string, you can just terminate the PHP tag `?>`  then put in HTML the way you normally would, and once your done with the HTML just put in `<?php` and continue on where you left off  -- dont forget to include things like  `}`

Answer (score 0):

Check your code for starters...What is `20204040` doing sitting in there? That will cause errors, So you need to get rid of that...

In your echo '' and with your concatenation, you have this

```
'<img src="image/$image"/>'.
```

Change it to this...

```
'<img src="image/'.$image.'"/>'.
```

You did it everywhere else but not in this instance.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for 20204040 i pasted by mistake but now instead of showing an image it displays small black diamond symbols with question marks

Comment: So what is the actual path to the image?

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the **entire image** in a blob column. So, you can't use this stored data as if it were a **simple path** to a image. So, no chance to do a simple: `<img src="image/$image">.`

You will need to "cast" the image through a php file that returns an image/jpg content-type, and use this php file as the path, like: `<img src="image_builder.php?image_id=999.php">`

See the accepted answer of this post: [How can I store and retrieve images from a MySQL database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php) for more detailed information.

Btw, if you find this too complex, consider storing only the path to an image stored in disk. In that case you only need a varchar column, not a blob one. And so, you may use your approach of echoing `<img src="image/$image_path">.`