# i am getting error in php while uploading image to databse using jquery, the data in variables arent passing maybe

Tags: php, jquery, html

My code is a form where it picks a file from the user, then send the data using jQuery to a PHP file where it gets the image content and displays it and in a success function: it alerts the data received from the PHP file. For example, the image received from the HTML page.

Actually, the code inserts the image into the database, but I plucked the code out and inserted a direct view of image in PHP file without inserting in the database because I wanted to make it short(database insertion code has no error: it inserts other variables provided with image and image stays blank)

Also am using my script on XAMPP localhost. So do not worry about that i am running it like file://...  . All is that i can't figure out why the data aren't being passed to php file.

**HTML:**

```
<input style="border:none" type="file" id="photo" />  <br>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#submit-form").click(function() {
  var formadata = {
    "photo": $("#photo").val(),
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: './enter-registration-form.php',
    data: formadata,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(val) {
      if (val == "done") {
        alert("Data Accepted");
      } else {
        alert(val);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$i = $_FILES['photo']['name'];

//get the content of the image and then add slashes to it
$imagetmp=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']));

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imagetmp).'" style="width:100px;height:autoborder:none">';
```

Now I am getting this error message:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: `photo` in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/SSNC/exam/enter-registration-form.php on line 5
>
> **Notice**:  Undefined index: `photo` in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/SSNC/exam/enter-registration-form.php on line 8
>
> **Warning**:  `file_get_contents()`: Filename cannot be empty in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/SSNC/exam/enter-registration-form.php on line 8

I can't figure out why this error is thrown.

Comment: Try changing $_FILES to $_POST (as your Ajax is sending to php via post method) failing that var_dump($_FILES) to see what it contains

Comment: Where are you actually handling the upload?

Comment: kerbholz can you elaborate ?

Comment: adam when $_POST['photo'] used it says undefined variable, and when i remove mimetype, cache:false, contenttype:false from jquery code and run the scripting then it shows the path name of the file selected saved in $_POST['photo'].

Comment: i think `cache: false, contentType: false, processData: false` i need to change this with respect to my need, i just copied this from internet because so of the solutions say using these solved their problem .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX file upload PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Comment: kerbholz am using it on localhost (XAMPP)

Comment: nigel i already have tried searching for issue for 2 days , none of them worked for me , so better you can help instead of providing already answered links.

Comment: are you only uploading the file or does your form has other entities as well?

Comment: it has other entries too , a few with type="text" and one field with type="file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work!

HTML:

```
<form id="my-upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="required-image" />
<button> Upload </button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
/* prevent default form action */
e.preventDefault();
/* get form element */
var formElement = document.getElementById("my-upload-form");
/* collect all form data from Form element */
var formData = new FormData(formElement);

$.ajax({
url: '/path-to-form-handler.php',
data: formData,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
method: 'POST',
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
});
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

/* for this example, $_FILES["required-image"] would be an array having image details */
echo $_FILES["required-image"]["name"];
echo $_FILES["required-image"]["type"];
echo $_FILES["required-image"]["tmp_name"];
echo $_FILES["required-image"]["size"];

?>
```

Comment: so if i have to use the image to insert into database then how should i proceed in php further ? like `$sql="INSERT INTO data VALES($_POST['a'],$_POST['b'],$_POST['c'],$_FILES['required-image']['temp_name'])";`

Comment: also saibbyweb can you explain your answer for learning purpose , please that would be very helpful .

Comment: also i would like to add that i have to save this image as base64 in database , and when the insertion is success then i have to print/display the image

Comment: well i tried `$imagetmp=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES["required-image"]["tmp_name"]));` to convert the file into base64 code so as for the purpose of storing in databse , but didn't worked .

Comment: the error is :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near line 1

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to store the image in database, instead we can upload the image on server and store its path in the database. It would be easier that way.

Comment: in short borther , i am told to be strictly restricted to database only

Comment: also i am having more fields with image (type=text, some select fields, file type) so using jquery & the above method you provided , maybe i need to do something more and i am not doing it thats why the sql error ? (and i echo'ed all the $_POST[''] values the variables do have the values , and i copies the sql into phpmyadmin sql and run the query the query also seemed fine, cause it worked there)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636877/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-images-from-a-mysql-database-using-php This might help.

Answer (score 2):

### Approach

You need to use [`new FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.

> The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of
>   `key/value` pairs representing form fields and their values, which can
>   then be easily sent using the `XMLHttpRequest.send()` method. It uses
>   the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to
>   "multipart/form-data".

So you don't actually have to declare a form tag and add inputs inside, yes it makes it easier if you have let us make a call assuming that you do not have a form tag.

### Problem

The problem in your script is that your `formdata` is a `json` rather than a `FormData()` interface object, which uses `formdataObject.append()` which appends a new value onto an existing key inside a `FormData` object, or adds the key if it does not already exist.

See code below which posts `email`, file `label` and a `file` to a PHP page without using form tag for the inputs.

### Without `<form>` tag

Assuming that your html looks like below without a form

```
<label>Your email address:</label>
<input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="userid" placeholder="email" required size="32" maxlength="64" />
<br />
<label>Custom file label:</label>
<input type="text" name="filelabel" size="12" maxlength="32" />
<br />
<label>File to stash:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" required />
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
```

Your javascript code will look like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='submit']").on('click', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        //START Append form data
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append(
            'userid', $("input[name='userid']").val());
        data.append(
            'label', $("input[name='filelabel']").val()
        );
        data.append('file', $("input[name='file']")[0].files[0], 'somename.jpg');
        //END append form data

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            success: function (data) {
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

And your `file.php` will look like below

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

This should show you the file inputs and file both of them in the console when you hit the `stash file` button.

### With `<form>` tag

If you have the inputs wrapped inside the form tag then your code will be changed on the following sections

- Change binding of `click` event to form `submit` event.
- Change button type to `submit` in the `HTML`.
- Get the form object.
- Use form object to initialize the `FormData()`.

See below How your HTML will look like

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
    <label>Your email address:</label>
    <input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="userid" placeholder="email" required size="32" maxlength="64" />
    <br />
    <label>Custom file label:</label>
    <input type="text" name="filelabel" size="12" maxlength="32" />
    <br />
    <label>File to stash:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>
```

And your javascript will look like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        var data = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            success: function (data) {
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all insert your input file tag in a form and use enctype="multipart/formdata"
to send an image otherwise you will not able to send image

Comment: so the form tag with enctype attribut is must ? and then i have to change jquery to $(#form).submit(..) .?

Comment: this is wrong , using `FormData()` object to submit form and files along with it has nothing to do with the form tag or the `enctype` attribute , you can still upload files using ajax without having even the form tag defined